# How to use distinct in SQL Server without order by

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I have a table `#temprajesh` with columns `idtask`, `taskname`. I am getting duplicate task id but I need a single value with same order of `idtask`.

When I tried below query

```
select idtask 
from #temprajesh 
group by  idtask,taskname
```

Using group by or distinct also am able to eliminate the duplicate values but the order of `idtask` column is changed to ascending.

I also have tried the below query using `rownumber` when I use `rownumber` am not able to eliminate the duplicate records but the order of idtask remains same

```
select distinct idtask, taskname, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by idtask) 
from #temprajesh
```

I need `idtask` column to be in same order which was before group by statement. I have the table data as

```
159480  power_10sites_5minhybrid_Multi_Site
159480  power_10sites_5minhybrid_Multi_Site
159480  power_10sites_5minhybrid_Multi_Site
159480  power_10sites_5minhybrid_Multi_Site
159480  power_10sites_5minhybrid_Multi_Site
159480  power_10sites_5minhybrid_Multi_Site
159480  power_10sites_5minhybrid_Multi_Site
159480  power_10sites_5minhybrid_Multi_Site
159480  power_10sites_5minhybrid_Multi_Site
159480  power_10sites_5minhybrid_Multi_Site
159481  123_8_Multi_Site
159481  123_8_Multi_Site
159481  123_8_Multi_Site
159481  123_8_Multi_Site
159481  123_8_Multi_Site
159481  123_8_Multi_Site
159481  123_8_Multi_Site
159481  123_8_Multi_Site
159481  123_8_Multi_Site
159481  123_8_Multi_Site
159482  _Multi_Site
159483  _Multi_Site
159484  _Multi_Site
159484  _Multi_Site
159485  123_10_Multi_Site
159485  123_10_Multi_Site
159485  123_10_Multi_Site
159485  123_10_Multi_Site
159485  123_10_Multi_Site
159485  123_10_Multi_Site
159485  123_10_Multi_Site
159485  123_10_Multi_Site
159485  123_10_Multi_Site
159485  123_10_Multi_Site
159486  123_11_Multi_Site
159486  123_11_Multi_Site
159486  123_11_Multi_Site
159486  123_11_Multi_Site
159486  123_11_Multi_Site
159486  123_11_Multi_Site
159486  123_11_Multi_Site
159486  123_11_Multi_Site
159486  123_11_Multi_Site
159486  123_11_Multi_Site
159487  300_Multi_Site
159487  300_Multi_Site
159487  300_Multi_Site
159487  300_Multi_Site
159487  300_Multi_Site
159487  300_Multi_Site
159487  300_Multi_Site
159487  300_Multi_Site
159487  300_Multi_Site
159487  300_Multi_Site
159488  301_Multi_Site
159488  301_Multi_Site
159489  123_12_Multi_Site
159489  123_12_Multi_Site
159410  gh_Multi_Site
159416  ujh_Multi_Site
159353  uh_Multi_Site
159402  g_Multi_Site
159347  sd_Multi_Site
159396  dfg_Multi_Site
159413  try_Multi_Site
159390  fgd_Multi_Site
159382  ghj_Multi_Site
159356  ertdsf_Multi_Site
159393  eg_Multi_Site
159350  jh_Multi_Site
159399  sdf_Multi_Site
159414  uhy_Multi_Site
159391  fg_Multi_Site
159385  R1_Multi_Site
159408  xcv_Multi_Site
159394  fgd_Multi_Site
159351  jh_Multi_Site
159388  fdg_Multi_Site
159411  gh_Multi_Site
159417  ui_Multi_Site
159354  ert_Multi_Site
159348  sd_Multi_Site
159405  gtr_Multi_Site
159397  tyu_Multi_Site
159389  tyu_Multi_Site
159412  tf_Multi_Site
159383  ergt_Multi_Site
159380  sdfsdf_Multi_Site
159406  gtr_Multi_Site
159400  sdf_Multi_Site
159349  jh_Multi_Site
159392  fg_Multi_Site
159409  gh_Multi_Site
159386  fdg_Multi_Site
159346  sd_Multi_Site
159352  uh_Multi_Site
159387  fdg_Multi_Site
159418  ty_Multi_Site
159404  gtr_Multi_Site
159335  gh_Multi_Site
159398  gr_Multi_Site
159415  fdg_Multi_Site
159384  R1_Multi_Site
159421  r_Multi_Site
159401  sdf_Multi_Site
159381  sdfsdf_Multi_Site
159395  sfgd_Multi_Site
159407  xcv_Multi_Site
```

I need the output as

```
159480  power_10sites_5minhybrid_Multi_Site
159481  123_8_Multi_Site
159482  _Multi_Site
159485  123_10_Multi_Site
159486  123_11_Multi_Site
159487  300_Multi_Site
159488  301_Multi_Site
159489  123_12_Multi_Site
159410  gh_Multi_Site
159416  ujh_Multi_Site
159353  uh_Multi_Site
159402  g_Multi_Site
159347  sd_Multi_Site
159396  dfg_Multi_Site
159413  try_Multi_Site
159390  fgd_Multi_Site
159382  ghj_Multi_Site
159356  ertdsf_Multi_Site
159393  eg_Multi_Site
159350  jh_Multi_Site
159399  sdf_Multi_Site
159414  uhy_Multi_Site
159391  fg_Multi_Site
159385  R1_Multi_Site
159408  xcv_Multi_Site
159394  fgd_Multi_Site
159351  jh_Multi_Site
159388  fdg_Multi_Site
159411  gh_Multi_Site
159417  ui_Multi_Site
159354  ert_Multi_Site
159348  sd_Multi_Site
159405  gtr_Multi_Site
159397  tyu_Multi_Site
159389  tyu_Multi_Site
159412  tf_Multi_Site
159383  ergt_Multi_Site
159380  sdfsdf_Multi_Site
159406  gtr_Multi_Site
159400  sdf_Multi_Site
159349  jh_Multi_Site
159392  fg_Multi_Site
159409  gh_Multi_Site
159386  fdg_Multi_Site
159346  sd_Multi_Site
159352  uh_Multi_Site
159387  fdg_Multi_Site
159418  ty_Multi_Site
159404  gtr_Multi_Site
159335  gh_Multi_Site
159398  gr_Multi_Site
159415  fdg_Multi_Site
159384  R1_Multi_Site
159421  r_Multi_Site
159401  sdf_Multi_Site
159381  sdfsdf_Multi_Site
159395  sfgd_Multi_Site
159407  xcv_Multi_Site
```

Comment: Basically, if you've not stored anything you can order by in the temp table, you're out of luck. Even if you do an un-ordered select (`SELECT * FROM #temprajesh`) twice in a row you're not guaranteed to get the same ordering.

Answer (score 8):

Data in a table is not inherently ordered you have to provide some way via a value or some logic to create a specific order. There is no way to guaranteed order unless you specify an `ORDER BY`.

But you should be able to return a single row for each `idtask` with `row_number()`. The problem with your original version is you aren't filtering the data to return only a single row and the `row_number()` isn't partitioned by the `idtask` values:

```
select idtask, 
    taskname
from 
(
  select idtask, 
    taskname, 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by idtask order by idtask) 
  from #temprajesh
) d
where rn = 1;
```

[See Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a51475/1). The subquery will create your unique value for each row in the `idtask` but then you'll only return one row.

Comment: I need the output in different format using the above query defaultly idtask is getting ordered by ascending which is not required (Idtask should retain the same order as above output specified)

Comment: @user2211918 Unless you have a column to order the data in that way, you cannot guarantee the order from a table.  You need some value/column to use for ordering.  It doesn't look like you have one - what logic are you using to determine that order?

Comment: @user2211918 If you are basing the order off the "number of entries" then you might be able to use `count` to help determine order similar to -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a51475/5

Comment: I don't have any column to determine the order but I need to maintain the same order which is in input data.Please help me if you have any solution

Comment: @user2211918 As I said, unless you provide some value or logic to order the data by you **can't** guarantee the order - it's not possible.  How are you determining the order for the output?  What logic are you using?  Is it by the count of the `idtask`?

Comment: @user2211918 Please read #3, *thoroughly*: http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/t-sql-tuesday-56-sql-server-assumptions/ If you want to maintain the order of insert, since I notice in your screen shot you are inserting one row at a time, add an identity column to your temp table.

Comment: Even though if we add identity column on what basis we can eliminate duplicate records?

Comment: @user2211918 If you add an identity, then you can use `row_number()` to filter out the duplicates

Comment: @user2211918 In a CTE say `SELECT identity_column, taskname, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY taskname ORDER BY identity_column)` and then select from the CTE `WHERE rn = 1 ORDER BY identity_column`.